Expected type 'Optional[(str) -> bool]', got 'bool' instead
I am writing a code for some Nueral Network, and I am trying to load images.
train_dataset = torchvision.datasets.ImageFolder(root="SmallSet/Train", is_valid_file=True)

Some of my images are corrupted so I added is_valid_file=True
, but I get the error Expected type 'Optional[(str) -> bool]', got 'bool' instead 
How can I fix this?

The error:
Expected type 'Optional[(str) -> bool]', got 'bool' instead

says that is_valid_file an optional field. But If you are passing something it must be a callable that takes one argument(which is the path of the file) and returns a boolean(which decides whether the file is corrupted or not).
Quoting from the docs:

is_valid_file (callable, optional) – A function that takes path of
an Image file and check if the file is a valid file (used to check of
corrupt files)

To solve this you could write a function like this to check whether the  image is broken or not.
from PIL import Image

def is_valid_image_file(path: str) -> bool:
    try: 
        img = Image.open(path)
        img.verify()
     except Exception: 
        return False
     else:
        return True

train_dataset = torchvision.datasets.ImageFolder(root="SmallSet/Train", is_valid_file=is_valid_image_file)

